# Chrome: Save and open a set of tabs in a new window

Tags: google-chrome, window-manager, browser-tabs

I have at least 10 tabs open at any time of the day. The problem is, I don't need half of them most the time.

I use different websites together depending on what I'm currently doing. If I study a foreign language, I always have a dictionary, google translator, and a thesaurus open in a seperate Chrome window.

If I write some code, I always have a set of documentation websites and Stackoverflow open.

Is it possible, that I save such a extern Chrome window with a certain set of tabs at a time, and close and reopen all those tabs in an extern window at the same time?

I checked [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko), but it can only save and reload all tabs in all windows, but can not reload only a set of tabs in their own window. As far as I saw.

Do you know any good solution for me?

Answer (score 1):

You could <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+click on all the links you would like to open in a new window and then drag one of them away to create new windows with only the selected tabs. Then you could right click one of the tabs in the new window and just select "bookmark all tabs", thus only bookmarking the selected tabs in the new window. Then just open all these saved tabs later on if you want to continue this session (by middle clicking the folder they are bookmarked in).

Comment: Good answer, could you possibly include a screenshot to further illustrate where these options are?